# ASP Classic coding on the Mac?

Tags: asp-classic

Anyone here do classic ASP development on the Mac?
The biggest thing that I'm looking for is a Web Preview that is capable of handling ASP Include files.
I personally use Textmate and Espresso for web development, but neither of those handle Include files.
My boss is in love with Dreamweaver but I'm loathe to adopt it because I've never liked using it.  If it's my only way to go then I'll have to but I was hoping someone knew of another environment that would work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coda is a decent mac editor. However I have also tried parallels and VMWare Fusion 3 with Visual Studio 2008. So far I have found that  VMWare and VS 2008 works the most efficiently and does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do Classic ASP Development on the MAC is to use Adobe Dreamweaver, with a second computer that has windows IIS installed.

On the windows pc. setup your web sites in IIS.  Make sure that the directories you use for the site are available on a share, or shared so that the mac can see them.

In your mac, setup dreamweaver to use the site that IIS is using to serve the files, and also update your hosts file to map to the IIS server's ip for the site you are working on.

You will be using Dreamweaver on mac to make changes directly on a website on an IIS Server.  The pc you use for IIS can be as cheap as $100.  Not much is needed to run IIS.

Comment: By the way, you could use virtual box or paralells or something else instead of having a physical machine for iis.  The point of my answer was that you cannot run iis on a mac.  A windows machine is required.  I use an old computer with a static IP for all my dev iis work.  A virtual machine would be just as good considering your mac has the resources and space to to run a child machine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Parallels and then you can run Windows on your Mac for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done ASP classic coding on a Mac in a few years, but for several years I worked as an ASP classic programmer and did most of my work on a Mac. To be honest, there wasn't much support. I had an ASP bundle for TextMate that did color coding, but I copied files to a testing server to actually check them out. (Of course, we used an old version of Dreamweaver, too, that didn't have great support for ASP either, so *no one* in the office that good ASP support.) I don't know if times have changed, but since ASP classic was getting a bit outdated even when I was an ASP classic developer, I'm guessing no one has bothered to improve support for it, especially on the Mac.