# How I edit and run an ASP site on a mac?

Tags: windows, macos, asp-classic

I'm a simple mortal, not a developer. My boss asked me if I can redesign an ASP website of a client, I, a foolish graphic designer, said yes. I only have to rewrite CSS and change some divs, EASY, piece of cake for me! BUT I have never had touched ASP... And we work on iMac, and I don't have access to the server where the site is, we only have Linux installed in our own server, my boss gave me the asp source code and I don't know what to do with it.

I have a laptop with windows 7 at home, but boss prefers that I work here with the mac.

Am I wrong or I have to run a virtual machine with windows server on this mac? is it there an easier solution to run ASP code on a mac?

-.- sorry for being a designer.

Comment: most likely ... the answer is VM. but you can bootcamp it too. Mono is another solution but you definitely would want to take advantage of Visual studio when it comes to c#

Comment: Same 'boss' should provide you with a Windows machine. He can rent it by the hour, eg. http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-workspaces-desktop-computing-in-the-cloud/. And if is classic ASP, then your CSS knowledge is useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess Ill try to do it on my laptop and ask for some homeoffice days... 

There is a document in the source code, it says the site is almost completely in ASP classic and a few functions in ASP NET, there is a .css too which is the one I pretend to edit, why is it useless my knowledge here? Thanks !

Comment: Don't know why the other commentor said your css knowledge would be useless. my best guess is he is taking a crack at IE's reluctance, until the newest versions, to implement most CSS functionality. caniuse.com will be your friend here.

Comment: Css runs on the client, Classic ASP runs on the server and uses vbscript, jScript or javascript language.

Comment: You could try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267112/asp-classic-coding-on-the-mac) and see if it's any use. But really that's the least of your issues. You're going to need a 'server' that can run the code even if that's just for testing alone. Your boss is being pretty unrealistic if he wants you to do this on the Mac only. You could download a VM as suggested, or use your home laptop. Whichever way ... *good luck*!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit ASP on a mac using any text editor.  SublimeText would work well and has extensions for ASP code highliting.

As for testing ASP code on a mac, debugging or actually running then your best bet is to run a virtual machine with IIS (or IIS express) web server.  In the most recent versions of IIS you actually need to enable classic asp.  If you are making small minor changes, you might be able with just deploying them to your live server and seeing if they run correctly.